# C++ getter function : const and non const

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

I'm writing a program with a robot class in C++. The following code, when I try to access the getter crash with

```
==19724== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
==19724== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x15788828 --> 0xffeffe990
==19724==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=68342473064 or greater
unknown location(0): fatal error in "trying": memory access violation at address: 0xffe801ff8: no mapping at fault address
```

Here is the getter code :

```
#ifndef ROBOT_MAP
#define ROBOT_MAP

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

class Robot{
protected : 

    int _y;
    int _x;
public : 

    Robot(int x, int y): _x(x), _y(y){};

    void setX(int x){_x = x;}
    void setY(int y){_y = y;}

    const int& getX() const {return _x;}
    int& getX(){return const_cast<int&>(static_cast <Robot &>(*this).getX());}
    const int& getY() const {return _y;}
    int& getY(){return const_cast<int&>(static_cast <Robot &>(*this).getY());}


};
#endif
```

I'm trying to implement the const and non const function correctly as I found it defined somewhere else on this site. The same kind of getter returning a `std::vector` works but as soon as try `SomeRobot.getX()`, it crashes.

I've been running it in valgrind and it didn't gave me much more information.

So what is wrong in the code that makes it crash ?

Comment: That default constructor is plain evil. Why did you write that?

Comment: Yep, that was on the first implementation. I need to remove it actually.

Comment: There's no need to return a constant reference for a simple getter function, just return by value. And the non-constant getters, why are you doing all this const casting when all you have to do is return the actual variables? If anything, do the opposite, that the non-const getters plainly return the variables, and the constant getters do a `const_cast` to `const Robot`, that just seems much safer to me.

Comment: Since you have a setter, I can't see a good reason for returning it by reference that would make this better than having `_x` be public.  Why don't you want to return the int by value `int getX() const { return _x; }`

Comment: I was just trying to understand how to do good const correct code. So I followed some "rule" that I can't seem to find again here on how you supposed to do it (if you don't want to just write the getter again). I know here it's pretty ugly :P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
int& getX(){return const_cast<int&>(static_cast <Robot &>(*this).getX());}
```

Since `*this` is cast to `Robot &` (i.e., not changed), the non-const version of `getX()` is called, making this function infinitely recursive. It goes on to die with a stack overflow.

Instead, write

```
//                                                     vvvvv-- here
int& getX(){return const_cast<int&>(static_cast <Robot const &>(*this).getX());}
```

to make `getX()` call `getX() const`. The same applies for `getY()`.

Obligatory note: Be very, very, **very** careful with `const_cast`. This is one of the few contexts where using it makes some sense<sup>1</sup> and is not insanely dangerous. Although, I have to say that the function bodies of `getX()` and `getY()` are short enough that I'd have no qualms duplicating them.

<sup>1</sup> That is to say, would make some sense if the functions were more complicated.

Comment: But why oh why do these gymnastics anyway. Just repeat the body of the getter for both const and non-const versions. These casts are confusing and unnecessary. `return _x` is all that is needed.

Comment: I know it is useless here but I just wanted to understand what was the correct way to do it in case the getter gets bigger and I don't want to re-write everything.

Comment: In this case, it's DRY taken to ridiculous extremes. The trick itself isn't completely insane for more complex functions, though.

Comment: @Wintermute: I fine example where it really makes sense is `strchr`.